# Does RegisterWaitForSingleObject run the callback in parallel if the event gets set again while it's still executing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety

I am using `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` with an Event handle (auto-reset event). The event is getting set in a separate thread.

If I don't pass `WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE` flag and the event gets set again while my `Callback` function is still executing, will it get called in parallel? Also does the Event get reset before or after my callback runs?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I mean if code in callback contains a busy loop, it's possible that the separate thread (which had set the event first time) could set the event again. And I am concerned if that `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` would just grab another worker thread from thread-pool and run the callback again while previous invocation didn't finish.

Comment: if you use auto-reset event, it will be reset before wait api return, so before your callback called. but if it can set again at any time by another thread - no sense ask this at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple threads in your thread pool, the callback could run concurrently.  If you need to prevent that you should add your own synchronization.

The event will be reset before your callback runs.

Comment: [New wait threads are created automatically when required. The wait operation is performed by a wait thread from the thread pool. By default, the thread pool has a maximum of 500 threads.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerwaitforsingleobject). It seems that  there are always multiple threads, so I will use a mutex for the callback. Thanks!